# How do I achieve different routing path for same destination in cisco router

Tags: cisco, router, asymmetric-routing

I want to route same destination packet coming from the different source s1 and S2, to different path something like this

```
ip route 192.168.221.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.222.1
ip route 192.168.221.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.120.1
```

How do I achieve it?

Comment: You need policy-based routing to route based on source address.

Comment: PBR will do it, but it is very resource intensive, so you need a very good reason to do it. PBR will punt the routing to the CPU, so you need to closely monitor your CPU usage and temperature, and you may need to get a bigger router to handle it.

Comment: PBR is supported in hardware on many platforms. I am sure the Catalyst 4500 and 6500 series can do it, and am almost certain that the 3850 can do PBR in hardware as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with policy based routing

```
ip access-list standard s1
 permit 192.168.221.1

ip access-list standard s2
 permit 192.168.221.2

route-map PBR permit 10
 match ip address s1
 set ip next-hop 192.168.120.1

route-map PBR permit 20
 match ip address s2
 set ip next-hop 192.168.120.50

interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip policy route-map PBR
```

In this example anything arriving on f0/0 is evaluated by the route-map, anything with a source address of 192.168.222.1 is forwarded to 192.168.120.1, anything with source address 192.168.222.2 is forwarded to 192.168.120.50

Comment: What about the rest of traffic it will be dropped?

Comment: No, it will use normal destination based routing in the IP routing table.  Route-maps operate differently with PBR, anything not matched just follows normal IP routing logic